# problem accessing @Autowired repository (JPA) in basic Spring-MVC (non-boot) project

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jpa, autowired

I set up a very basic spring-mvc project (non-boot) to access through JPA my database. But I keep getting:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
```

which is the result of the application not being able to find and initialise

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;
```

I wanted to set up JPA according to [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa). Without initialisation of the UserRepository, the application works just fine.

Can anyone help me? I went through thousand of tutorials and most of them are for Spring Boot application, and I do not want to use Spring Boot at this time. How can I set it correctly?

Here is my code, the project is created in IntelliJ, using maven-archetype-webapp and with below configuration:

ApplicationConfig.java

```
package dominikazb.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "dominikazb")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}


@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "dominikazb" });

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://database_hosted_on_heroku");
    dataSource.setUsername( "username" );
    dataSource.setPassword( "password" );
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}
}
```

User.java

```
package dominikazb.beans;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private int user_id;
private String username;
private String password;

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "user_id=" + user_id +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

HomeController.java

```
package dominikazb.controllers;
import dominikazb.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String takeMeHome() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchDatabase() {
    return "list";
} 
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package dominikazb.repositories;
import dominikazb.beans.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository <User, Integer> {
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-web-api -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
   <version>8.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   <version>8.0.19</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

application-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="dominikazb" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Full exception:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dominikazb.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dominikazb.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: Can you post complete exception trace?

Comment: Sure, I just edited the file and added a complete exception.

Comment: There is above the application-context.xml file, the rest of the configuration is included in ApplicationConf.java file (also listed above)

Comment: In HomeController use userRepository instead of repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CrudRepository is @NoRepositoryBean, you don't need to add @Repository over UserRepository.

Add below to your configuration file and if spring-data-jpa is not available in your maven dependency then add it to your pom.xml,

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"dominikazb.repositories"})
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried before with @EnableJpaRepositories, but I did not include the word basePackages, just added the package in double quotes, and that's probably why it did not work. Thanks!!!!